# LS in directory does not return in certain directories

Tags: ssh, backup, mega, rclone

I've got a Duplicati installation pushing to a remote SSH server. This server has a FUSE connection to Mega (I know duplicati has Mega support, but Duplicati stores the password in plain text and Mega doesn't support other authentication methods, so we use a proxy).
While a backup is running, the proxy is responsive and can be accessed via SSH exclusively via PK, but while a backup is running, the contents of the directory the backup is pushing to, is inaccessible. The following commands all hang with no output.

```bash
$ echo value > /mnt/backup/test
$ ls /mnt/backup
$ umount /mnt/backup
```

I suspect it's because of how we connect to Mega - through rclone. Which as far as I can understand, doesn't store the files temporarily, instead writes directly to Mega, and happens to be strictly serial. Which begs the question, how come I can access other locations on this Mega account through SSH (rclone) while a backup is running, but not the actual output directory?

Is this expected behaviour, and what happens when the Duplicati backup gets interrupted while the directory still has (what I assume to be) a lock on it?

Thanks

Comment: If `rclone` uses `rsync` then it may be that the target is hidden (due to `rsync` prefixing it with a `.`) until rsync is done. Try `ls -a` on the parent directory to check.

Comment: hm. the output is pretty much what I expect it to be. There's nothing out of the ordinary...
https://imgur.com/a/DhnEKz8
To add to your commend before, I installed rclone. Not rsync...